# Problems when trying to replace a sub-string of unequal length

Tags: c++, string

I have a function that replaces a sub-string with another:

```
std::string replaceAll(std::string data, std::map <std::string, std::string> dict){
  for(std::pair <std::string, std::string> entry : dict){
      size_t start_pos = data.find(entry.first);
      while(start_pos != std::string::npos){
        data.replace(start_pos, entry.second.length(),entry.second);
        start_pos = data.find(entry.first, start_pos + entry.second.size());
      }

  }
  return data;
}
```

If the original string was `ls llllllllllllll` and I wanted to substitute ls with `ls --color=auto` it would do this
`ls --color-autolllll`. How can I avoid this overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `replace` needs to be the count of characters from the original string that you want to replace. So you need:

```
data.replace(start_pos, entry.first.length(), entry.second);
                     // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  length of original string
```